# Как сделать INSERT/UPDATE столбец типом JSON

Tags: java, sql, spring

```
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO Contract (createdBySid, createdByName, file_id, fileCode, code, accountHolders, accountHolderIds, deliveryAddress, deliveryDate, signDate," +
        "amount, type, description, orderStatus, createdDate, sid, version, lastModifiedDate, lastModifiedBySid, lastModifiedByName) " +
        "VALUES (:#{principal.sid}, :#{principal.fullName},:#{#contractDTO.fileId}, :#{#contractDTO.fileCode}, json_object, json_object, json_object," +
        ":#{#contractDTO.deliveryDate}, :#{#contractDTO.signDate}, :#{#contractDTO.amount}, :#{#contractDTO.type}, :#{#contractDTO.description}," +
        ":#{#contractDTO.orderStatus}, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UUID(), 0, null, null, null)", nativeQuery = true)
void saveContractFromTrigger(@Param("contractDTO") final ContractDTOSync contractDTO);
```

Вместо json_object должен быть обьект со всеми его полями. Как добавить json в этот столбец?

Comment: Так в чём проблема-то - в том, как свернуть объект в JSON значение в Java, чтобы передать его в запрос, или в том как изменять хранящийся в базе данных JSON?

Comment: В том как свернуть объект в JSON значение, не просто json string, json_object("key", "value")

Comment: ГДЕ он будет "сворачиваться"? в программе на Java, в Java-коде? если да - то при чём тут SQL, а если нет, то при чём тут Java?

Comment: Опишите точнее вопрос. Мне не понятно откуда берется json_object. В примере кода его нет. Могу предположить, что кроме тех полей вы хотите еще запихать в таблицу json объект?